# Generate documentation from programmatic drools rules

Tags: java, drools

I'm working on a project which uses Drools to validate certain java objects. We have lots of these rules now, and even though many were historically created from decision tables, many are not. This makes it hard to get an overview of which rules actually apply to a specific type of object.

I was thinking I could automatically generate some sort of documentation from the programmatic .drl rules. After some research, I've managed to extract a lot of useful information from the LHS (when clause) programmatically like this:

```java
RuleImpl rule = KieContainer.getKieBase().getKiePackages().get(index).rules.get(ruleIndex)
GroupElement whenGroup = rule.getLhs()
```

I think this is enough for the "when:" clause. However, it seems like Drools does not have much information on the "then:" clause available programmatically. It should be accessible from `rule.consecuence`, but from what I've gathered it doesn't really tell me much more than what class of object is created (I really need to know it's parameters). For example, in the following case:

```java
then
        insert(new Valideringsfejl("rta014.5", FejltypeHelper.MAA_IKKE_ANGIVES, "planlagtKapacitetIkkeAngivetSol"));
```

I am interested in the arguments `"rta014.5", FejltypeHelper.MAA_IKKE_ANGIVES` and `"planlagtKapacitetIkkeAngivetSol"`. So is there a way to get this information without parsing the source code myself, or can this kind of documentation be generated in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very naive approach, because rules can become very complex. While yours might be on the simpler side, there is no out-of-the-box solution for this because of this complexity. The best you *might* be able to do for a general solution is a third-party tool to generate graphs that trace the old rete trees in Drools 5 or so. (I built one of those tracing tools as an intern; it was one of the hardest projects of my career and the end result wasn't particularly useful.)

The other reason it wouldn't make sense for such a tool to exist in the general sense is that every rule base is inherently tied to the application its supporting. From your post, I see that your rules rely heavily on inserting facts into working memory -- and that's what you're most interested in. I have supported rulesets with 10,000+ rules which never call insert at all. An insert-based solution which would satisfy your use case, would be useless for my application.

---

So you're left with going down the route of writing your own parser which -- honestly -- doesn't sound like such a terrible prospect.

If all you want to know is the name of the rule and the 'insert' values on the right hand side ("then"), I figure there's at least three ways to do this:

- Programmatically: get the `KieBase`, iterate across all rules, and use the `RuleImpl` and related objects to get this information. You'd need to figure out how to get the `Consequence` to spit out the data you need, which might involve actually invoking it in a sandboxed context. 
  I include this option for completeness, but I'm not entirely positive it will work. I've never had much reason to work with `Consequence` directly.
- Via the grammar: Probably a subset of the previous, these rules have a formal grammar, so you could probably use ANTLR to model and parse them. Personally this sounds like it's a bit over-architected for your problem.
- Parse the DRL *files* directly. At the end of the day, the rule are plain-text DRL before they get compiled into KieBases. The rules are well-formed (see bit about the formal grammar), so they shouldn't be too odious to parse. I usually dislike recommending regex, but in this case it would be pretty trivial to identify each rule (conveniently bracketed by `rule "<name>"` and `end`) and then pulling out the rule name and any `insert` statements and their arguments in the "then" clause.

---

There is one more approach which you have not considered. When I ran into a similar situation with a legacy ruleset (~40,000 rules) which were terribly complex from a business perspective (eg. after 10 years in the industry I still couldn't tell you if what it was doing was correct), but not so much from a technical implementation perspective, I actually used my unit tests to document the rulesets so my Business Analysts could understand what I was actually doing (and verify the rules for us.)

To do this I used BDD (behavior driven testing) and a language called Gherkin which described the rule, its triggers, and its consequences in plain English. Then I used the testing tool Cucumber to actually execute those Gherkin test cases as-is by firing the rules. In that way I had both a test and a human-readable description for each rule, and since these were treated and executed as unit tests, any modification to the rule which would violate its human-readable contract would cause the test to fail (thus requiring it to be updated.) Win-win, from our perspective. But I also had 3 interns to help me write those 40,000 Gherkin test cases.

I have a [toy project](https://github.com/roddy/drools-and-cucumber) demonstrating how these technologies work together on GitHub if you're interested in this approach. Unfortunately I don't have examples of the other approaches that I presented because -- as I discussed previously -- such solutions would not be particularly general and would be so application-specific to be practically useless outside of that context.

Comment: Thank you so much for a great response! I think there are probably two alternatives for me now:

1. Just document everything manually. We don't have an extreme amount of rules, so it would be possible and ensure the most correct/detailed result. Of course, this will have to be updated continuously.
2. Parse the .drl file myself. This is also feasible, and not actually that complex as all our rules are pretty uniform.

Comment: Honestly the tests-as-documentation approach was a lifesaver when I implemented it because it served as both validation and documentation. But as usual you should consider your particular use cases. Glad I could be of service.

Comment: I think the solution I might end up with is adding custom documentation to each rule in the .drl files that are then parsed. This ensures that we can add more detailed documentation and place it where it will help the developers the most. This should also ensure that we can remember to update it, as it is close to our code :)